# Calculate time since user input and multiply times hourly rate in JS

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm trying to create a simple time/salary tracker.
The user inputs time they started work and then a counter counts up the numbers of hours and minutes since clock-in and also the amount of money made in that time
It should also update the time and salary every 1s (setInterval(function, 1000))
I've been trying to get it right but can't seem to get the Date() working like I want it, would appreciate a nudge in the right direction
Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<input id="input" type="time">
<button onclick="live()">run</button>
<!---->
<p id="output">Output</p>
<script>
       function live() {
           var seconds = 60;
           var minutes = seconds * 60;
           var hours = minutes * 60;

           var rate = 75;

           var input = document.getElementById('input');
           var output = document.getElementById('output');

           var now = new Date();
           var clock_in = input.value;

           var elapsed = now.toString();

           output.innerHTML = now.getHours() + " " +  now.getMinutes() + " " + now.getSeconds() + " " + now.getMilliseconds();
       }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your JS try with us ? So people can help you to fix your errors

Comment: added it now, sorry about that. Haven't achieved much yet but got completely stuck and can't think how to get further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to accept a date too, you can find a demo [working here](https://jsbin.com/dudehulune/1/edit?html,output)

Basically the problem is that you need to have a valid Date Object

Explained without inputs the basic code works like this

```
// Init Time - valid Object time
var initTime = new Date(2017, 06, 5) // today Date, month start with 0

// time now 
var now = new Date()

// diference in millisecond
var diference = now - initTime;

// rate scale
var rate = 75;
var scale = 75/3600000 // millisecond in a hour

// money 
var money = scale * diference;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that definitely helps :)